# MySQL problema de base de datos

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy entrando a mi Cpanel y cuando entro a MySQL, me arroja un error así

> Error while connecting to MySQL: (XID sdgzwf) Database Connect Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Error while connecting to MySQL: (XID sdgzwf) Database Connect Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mysql.pm line 173.

¿Qué se puede hacer?

Comment: Esto talvez podria ayudarte con tu problema Saludos
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que si estás entrando al cPanel, es porque eres un usuario de un servidor de hosting. Si es así, comunícate por el medio más apropiado con el soporte técnico de tu proveedor, ya que tienen una mala configuración en el cPanel o en el phpMyAdmin. Ten a mano el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo y ellos lo resolverán.

Comment: podrías agregar el log del servidor , o del mysql tienes acceso mediante phpmyadmin?